# Disable switching to a previous program when clicking on already active program in Windows 10 taskbar

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows 10, desktop mode, taskbar with grouping disabled. Run two programs, switch to one of them, then click on its taskbar representation. Back in the good old Win2K/WinXP days that would do nothing, which was very intuitive behavior - the program already has a focus, so selecting it on the taskbar again should not change anything. But in Win10 the behavior is different and very disorienting - essentially if you click on an active program in the taskbar, it works like Alt-Tab, i.e. switches to a program that had focus before the current one, which is a completely different program. How can I disable this?

Clarification: I am happy with Alt-Tab and do not want to disable Alt-Tab shortcut, I use it a lot when I want to switch to the previous program, I want to disable switching to the previous program when I click on the active program in the taskbar.

Comment: if you click on an active program in the taskbar, it works like Alt-Tab,  ... Not on my computers. Check if you installed something to cause this behaviour.

Comment: No, I see this behavior on a clean install of Win10 Pro.

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to write something out in Powershell to affect this behavior.
However, which edition of Windows 10 you are using, may effect your ability to do that.  If you are using **Windows10 Home** for example,  changing anything that deep in the OS pretty darn difficult.
Assuming that you are using Pro or Enterprise and you are Admin on the computer, I would start with looking at the registry.

There's a thread here with similar issue, I dunno if this will help, but heres the link.
https://superuser.com/a/644106/772582

Good luck, m8!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: In my humble opinion the majority of this answer is commentary, the rest of the answer, is a link to an existing answer.  If an existing answer, answers this question, it should be flagged as a duplicate

Comment: I followed the link and tried what was suggested there. It does not solve the problem in Win10 Pro.