# Windows 11 clicking taskbar icons doesn't bring the program window to the front

Tags: windows, windows-11

I have an issue with Windows 11 and its already opened taskbar programs. By clicking the icon the program's window is not brought to the front *if the particular program has multiple instances/windows open*. If it has only 1, then it works. If multiple, nothing basically happens and I have to Alt + Tab to bring it to the front.

I have

1. Upgraded Windows 11 from Windows 10 (not a fresh install)
2. Installed [Explorer patcher](https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher)
3. Uninstalled Explorer patcher when it stopped working after a system update
4. Noticed this issue.

How to make the taskbar work so that by clicking the icon on the taskbar the particular program would be brought to the front even if it has multiple instances open?

[image: Click does not bring File explorer on front]

*Pic 1. If a program e.g. File explorer has more than 1 instance already open, clicking it on the taskbar does nothing*

Comment: do you have any third party applications which are related to the taskbar? I get this same problem and restarting DisplayFusion usually solves it. However I do not know if DisplayFusion is causing it, or if restarting it fixes an underlying other issue

Comment: Is the taskbar set to be Always On Top? Does clicking on an empty spot in the taskbar help?

Comment: `do you have any third party applications which are related to the taskbar?`
I had this https://github.com/valinet/ExplorerPatcher but uninstalled it. Could it have broken it?

`Is the taskbar set to be Always On Top?`
Yes it is. Clicking an empty spot doesn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have multiple instances/windows of the apps that have issues open? Does explorer.exe restart help when it happens?

Comment: `Do you have multiple instances/windows of the apps that have issues open?` Yes! Indeed, if multiple instances of a particular program are open it fails to bring it to the front, if only 1, it works. 
`Does explorer.exe restart help when it happens?` Unfortunately, that won't help, the problem persists.

Comment: @anmatika and did you upgrade from Windows 10? Or is it fresh WIndows 11 install? Edit the question whenever you add additional info, please, BTW.

Comment: `did you upgrade from Windows 10? Or is it fresh WIndows 11 install?` I upgraded from Win 10.

Comment: I dont think there is any fix for it.  One of the many reasons I will not be going to Win11,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to my own question. It turned out that having the taskbar on the top was causing the issue.
Had to bring it back to the default position on the bottom and the problem was fixed. Now hovering on the programs in the taskbar would show the popup.

You can bring the taskbar back to the bottom by changing the value from  `01` to `03` in the registry in
`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\StuckRects3` as in the image below.

[image]

It would be nice to have the taskbar at the top, but apparently, it is not properly supported in Win 11.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an intentional behavior by Microsoft. It's been like this in Windows from at least 9 years ago. Please see [Change behavior of windows taskbar when switching programs](https://superuser.com/questions/644101/change-behavior-of-windows-taskbar-when-switching-programs). Windows 11 makes it apparent by force grouping taskbar icons and this is the exact behavior as the topic I mentioned. Looking at the answer attached screenshot, I assume it was Windows 7. Unfortunately, Windows 11 doesn't allow you to ungroup taskbar icons unless you are using Insider build on 'Dev' channel.

I am using vanilla Windows 11 on stable release, no Explorer Patcher installed.